# Understanding double recursion with print statement

Tags: java, recursion

I understand recursion when it is only called on itself once, and I sort of understand recursion when there is two, as one recursion has to finish first or something before the second can begin.

I am trying to understand the Towers of Hanoi, But what I really don't understand is the order the lines of code are read in when there is two recursions with a print statement.

Could someone break down the order simply? I have created this simple example (where test(3); )

And why does the print statement run?, isn't it invoked on itself immediately?

```
public static void test(int n){

    if(n>0){
        test(n-2);    
        test(n-1);
        System.out.println("print " + n); 
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I really don't understand is the order the lines of code are read in. Could someone break down the order simply?_" You can use a debugger to see how the flow goes when executed.

Comment: The print statement only runs once all intermediate method calls have returned , so the intermediate method calls will print and return before the current one.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the debugger to show the print statements.  Running it through normal steps only shows the line it reads. @berger, so everytime the method calls itself it executes the print statement is that right?

Comment: @DavidB : yes the new calls to the method, made inside the current method call,  will print first .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not an exact implementation of TOH.

Here's the recursion tree and execution order of your code's statements (see it to believe it):

Let n = 4

```
                 4

       /                  \
      2                    3
  /      \            /         \
 0        1           1          2
       /     \      /   \     /     \
      -1      0    -1    0   0       1
                                   /   \
                                  -1    0

test(4)
test(2)
test(0)
test(1)
test(-1)
test(0)
print(1)
print(2)
test(3)
test(1)
test(-1)
test(0)
print(1)
test(2)
test(0)
test(1)
test(-1)
test(0)
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
print(4)
```

The function call sequence can be traced by doing a pre-order traversal of the tree. The print statements will be executed for the nodes where node-value is greater than 0, and after both the children of that node have returned.

Comment: 3 instead of 1 in one place.

Comment: Edit: So the order it prints is, it goes to the end of each branch then goes back up the tree? e.g. left branch = 1,2.   rightleft branch = 1.  right right branch = 1234?

Comment: Just look at the tree and do a preorder traversal of it. Print statement is the third statement inside the loop after to function calls. So, it is executed after the two function calls return the control back to the current function.

Comment: The order of printing can be traced in a bottom-up fashion. It executes the left child, then the right child and then prints the node.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to elaborate it via diagrams. Have a look!
Lat `n = 3`; 
[image]